# How to scrape a JSON page with JavaScript and collect data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-scraping

I want to scrape `https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json/` and collect the price of bitcoin, saving it to a variable. So far here is my js/jQuery code

```
$.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json/') + '&callback=?', function(data){
    console.log(data.contents);
    var za = $((data.contents).find("rate_float").text();
    alert(za)
}));
```

I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>   and it points to line:

```
var za = $((data.contents).find("rate_float").text();
```

No idea what's wrong. I've checked it over and over but all parentheses are closed. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Remove a bracket from `$((` <- should only be one

Comment: You miscounted your parentheses.

Comment: `$(data.contents).find("rate_float").text()` `<-` I don't know what you really want to do.

Comment: $((data.contents).find("rate_float").text();  has an extra bracket.

Comment: Ok. I've removed the bracket. Do you know what I could use instead of "rate_float" to capture the bitcoin price?

Comment: @KevinB I added answer, hope it will work as per the expectation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned value is a JSON string. You need to parse in order to convert that string to a js object like:

```
{
     "time": {
         "updated": "Mar 28, 2018 16:58:00 UTC",
         "updatedISO": "2018-03-28T16:58:00+00:00",
         "updateduk": "Mar 28, 2018 at 17:58 BST"
     },
     "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
     "bpi": {
         "USD": {
             "code": "USD",
             "rate": "7,882.7938",
             "description": "United States Dollar",
             "rate_float": 7882.7938
         },
         "BTC": {
             "code": "BTC",
             "rate": "1.0000",
             "description": "Bitcoin",
             "rate_float": 1
         }
     }
 }
```

In order to get the USD rate_float you can write:

```
var za = JSON.parse(data.contents).bpi.USD.rate_float;
```

The full code:

```js
$.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' +
        encodeURIComponent('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json') + '&callback=?', function (data) {
    console.log(data.contents);
    var za = JSON.parse(data.contents).bpi.USD.rate_float;
    alert(za)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo**

```js
// handles the click event, sends the query
function getSuccessOutput() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json',
        complete: function (response) {
            $('#output').html(JSON.parse(response.responseText).bpi.USD.rate_float);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#output').html('there was an error!');
        },
    });
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput();"> Get USD price </a>
<hr>
<div id="output">Click on link to get the output</div>
```